# Is it possible to update an entire record using an object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I was wondering if I could update a record (entire row) given a replacement activerecord object.

Something like

```
Car.find_by(number: 1) = replacement_information_for_car_1
```

where `replacement_information_for_car_1` is a `Car` activerecord object that I would like to use to replace the old record currently on the table.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
attributes = replacement_information_for_car_1.attributes
attributes.delete('id') # and anything else you don't want/can't be copied
Car.find_by(number: 1).update(attributes)
```

Not the cutest thing in the world, but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about ActiveRecord objects is that they have a unique identifier that you don't want to override. You'll have to assign the attributes without the id, that is most likely to be `nil` in your example.

```
Car.find_by(number: 1).update(replacement_information_for_car_1.attributes.except(:id))
```

That's a long line that can be refactored to something like

```
new_attributes = replacement_information_for_car_1.attributes.except(:id)
Car.find_by(number: 1).update(new_attributes)
```